# Google Visualization Line Chart Overlay/Emphasis

Tags: gwt, charts, google-api, google-visualization

I have two sets of data, a double and a boolean.

I want to graph the double and emphasize the data when the boolean is True.

Here's the complex part, from the business case:

1) Dashed, 2px, blue line for "normal", solid, 4px, red line for "emphasized".
 - This can be done by duplicating the double into another column where the boolean column is true.

2) Data is not perfectly congruous, missing some data where we have a boolean and vice-versa.
 - This means interpolateNulls should be on, but that means we can't use the solution from #1, since you cannot set interpolateNulls on a per-series basis.

3) The Color/Style for the bold section should be listed in the legend.
 - Cannot do this with an Emphasis or Style Role, only with #1.

I have tried the Emphasis role (can't style it at all, not in legend) and the Style role (can't change dash style, not in legend).

I'm using the final official gwt-visualization library.

Our requirements person will reluctantly give up dashed lines, but legend is a must-have.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have managed to jury rig something together by adding a calculated column full of nulls to put an arbitrary label on the legend, but that feels really hacky.

Comment: still probably easier than trying to build your own legend...

Comment: When you say `the final official gwt-visualization library` what exactly do you mean? (since the maven lib hasn't been updated since 2009)

Comment: I mean the one on Maven with a version of 1.0.2 that hasn't been updated since 2009.  :)

(And it was actually updated in 2011 with a new Readme saying it was no longer being updated.)